# How is code working after Optimising?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, disassembly

While studying Compiler optimizations,  I simply compiled following piece of code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct fraction {
    int num ;
    int denum ;
};

int main()
{
  struct fraction pi;
  pi.num = 22;
  pi.denum = 7;
  return 0;
}
```

using

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

When I disassemble this, I get :

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
sub    $0x10,%esp
movl   $0x16,-0x8(%ebp)
movl   $0x7,-0x4(%ebp)
mov    $0x0,%eax
leave  
ret
```

But if I apply optimizations like :

```
gcc test.c -o test -O3
```

all I get in disassembly is :

```
push   %ebp
xor    %eax,%eax
mov    %esp,%ebp
pop    %ebp
ret
```

Without Optimizations the values 22 and 7 where clearly visible in disassembly and I could clearly understand how the code worked but where are those values now after optimizations ? how is the code working now ? Please somebody explain .

Comment: The code essentially does nothing and the compiler knows that.

Comment: By "denum" do you mean "denom"? By "with" do you mean "without"? I know it's late, but attention to detail is somewhat important when talking about compiler optimisations...

Comment: Your program doesn't do anything; the optimizer figured that out and changed it to a program that does nothing (but return 0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your code doesn't effectively do anything externally visible that would have unpredictable side effects, the creation of the struct is simply **eliminated completely,** and now all your code does is returning 0 from `main()`.

(If you tell the compiler that it does indeed need to create the struct because it may be modified by someone/something else, it won't get rid of the code. Declare your variables as `volatile` and you'll see it in the assembler.)

Comment: Or print them or return them. Do something with the values that requires an effect outside the program.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler determined that `pi` was never used outside of that scope, and since there were no side effects, optimized away that whole variable, along with the assignments.

The resulting assembly code pretty much loads `0` into `eax`, fiddles with stack pointers, and then returns.